# Проблема с Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Мне нужно отправить ссылку через Intent.

Ссылка имеет вид http://www.google.com.

Когда я отправляю строку с такой ссылкой,при получении через getStringExtra, ссылка имеет вид google.com

В моём коде в str2 находится эта ссылка. По логом видно,что она преображается только тогда,когда при нажатии на уведомление мы переходим в другой Активити,в котором мы обрабатываем эту ссылку.

Код оповещения:

```
 public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        Notification notification=new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Status bar",
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY,str2);
        Log.i(TAG,str2);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Оповещение")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_KEY,notification);
```

Код активити, на которую переходим при нажатии:

```
public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    XWalkView web;
    String url;
    public static final String TAG = "WebActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**Растянуть окно на весь экран**/
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        url=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY);

        Log.i(TAG,url);
        //Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
        web=(XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.web_xwalkview);
        web.load(url, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Update:
изменил немного код
MainActivity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL_PUSH",str2);
        Log.i(TAG,str2);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

WebActivity:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
url=intent.getStringExtra("URL_PUSH");
```

Сейчас url=null пишет

Comment: Да ну бред. Если у тебя
`String str2 = "http://www.google.com";`
то и передать он должен эту строку один в один.

Comment: @YaPV я согласен,сейчас вообще не принимает ничего,пишет мол url=null и ошибку соответственно выбивает. Я уже с ума схожу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблема у вас с `KEY`. Попробуйте передать вот так

```
intent.putExtra("URL", "http://www.google.com");
```

На принимающей стороне

```
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
```

У меня выходит все как задумано

```
I/log:url :   - http://www.google.com
```

**upd.**

Попробуйте изменить -

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

на

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Я не понимаю что твориться,но сейчас вообще getStringExtra не находит строку.Пишут мол url=null,но как?Перед переходом в новое активити я смотрю строку,которую я передаю и там всё есть